# Image not displaying in local host in my asp site

Tags: asp.net

I am loading an asp  image into my site and its showing in the design view but when I run it on the local host it wont display the image.

```
<div><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" src="~/images/FusionChart.png" /></div>
```

the image is stored in "images" folder within the root and the image name is the exact same as in the div so Im confused as to why is wont display. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your path is incorrect. Please read this article, may be help you

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx
```

If not there is different

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/FusionChart.png"/>


<img src="~/images/FusionChart.png" alt=""/>
```

Comment: Thanks my problem was the "src". Should have had ImageUrl in so thanks for the help. Shuould have seen this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **src** attribute name to **ImageUrl** property name